# The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'Modules' includes related records

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, exception, datagridview

Having a problem with deleting records this exception keeps occurring.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'Modules' includes related records.

```
Public Class frmStudentDatabase

    Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=StudentDatabase.accdb")
    Dim objStudentDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Students", objConnection)
    Dim objStudentCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objStudentDA)
    Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()
    Dim objModuleDA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From Modules", objConnection)
    Dim objModuleCB As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(objModuleDA)


    Private Sub frmStudentDatabase_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Call the sub procedure that will fill the dataset
        'Create (Relationships) and Retrieve all Student_ID numbers

        Retrieve()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboStudents.SelectedIndexChanged

        FillStudentDetails()
        FillModuleDetails()

    End Sub

    Public Sub Retrieve()

        objDataSet.Clear()

        objStudentDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Students")
        objStudentDA.Fill(objDataSet, "Students")

        objModuleDA.FillSchema(objDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "Modules")
        objModuleDA.Fill(objDataSet, "Modules")

        objDataSet.Relations.Clear()
        objDataSet.Relations.Add("Students2Modules", objDataSet.Tables("Students").Columns("Student_ID"), _
                             objDataSet.Tables("Modules").Columns("Student_ID"))

        'Empty combo box
        cboStudents.Items.Clear()

        'Loop through each row, adding the Student_ID to the combobox
        Dim i As Integer, strCurrentID As String
        For i = 1 To objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Count
            strCurrentID = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows(i - 1).Item("Student_ID")
            cboStudents.Items.Add(strCurrentID)
        Next
        'Select first item in the list
        cboStudents.SelectedIndex = 0

        FillStudentDetails()
        FillModuleDetails()

    End Sub

    Public Sub FillStudentDetails()
        Dim objRow As DataRow
        objRow = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Find(cboStudents.SelectedItem)
        txtStudentID.Text = objRow.Item("Student_ID")
        txtStudentName.Text = objRow.Item("Student_Name")
        txtStudentAddress.Text = objRow.Item("Student_Address")
    End Sub

    Public Sub FillModuleDetails()
        Dim objStudent As DataRow, objModule As DataRow
        Dim strModuleEntry As String

        'Clear any existing modules
        lstModules.Items.Clear()

        'Find the current student record
        objStudent = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Find(cboStudents.SelectedItem.ToString)
        For Each objModule In objStudent.GetChildRows("Students2Modules")
            strModuleEntry = objModule.Item("Module_ID") & "," & objModule.Item("Module_Name") &
            "," & objModule.Item("Module_Desc")
            lstModules.Items.Add(strModuleEntry)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet.Tables("Modules")
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        Dim objRow As DataRow
        Dim objRowModules As DataRow
        Dim RowIndex As Integer
        objRow = objDataSet.Tables("Students").NewRow

        objRow.Item("Student_Name") = InputBox("Please Enter Student Name:")
        objRow.Item("Student_Address") = InputBox("Please Enter Student Address:")

        'Add data row to table
        objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Add(objRow)

        objStudentDA.Update(objDataSet, "Students")

        'Set up the module data row object
        objRowModules = objDataSet.Tables("Modules").NewRow

        'Find the number of the last row
        RowIndex = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Count - 1

        'Tell vb.net to get the Student_ID value from the last row
        objRowModules.Item("Student_ID") = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows(RowIndex)("Student_ID")
        objRowModules.Item("Module_Name") = InputBox("Please Enter Module Name:")
        objRowModules.Item("Module_Desc") = InputBox("Please Enter Module Description:")

        'Add to the DB
        objDataSet.Tables("Modules").Rows.Add(objRowModules)

        'Update the data adapter
        objModuleDA.Update(objDataSet, "Modules")

        MessageBox.Show("New record saved", "Saved")
        Retrieve()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        'Code to modify an existing record
        Dim objRowCurrent As DataRow
        objRowCurrent = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Find(cboStudents.SelectedItem.ToString)

        'We cannot modify the ID as it is an AutoNumber
        objRowCurrent("Student_Name") = txtStudentName.Text
        objRowCurrent("Student_Address") = txtStudentAddress.Text
        objStudentDA.Update(objDataSet, "Students")
        objDataSet.AcceptChanges()

        'Now that we made changes, we need to retrieve the new data
        Retrieve()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'Dim i As integer, strCurrentID As String
        Dim StudentName As String
        Dim StudentFound As Boolean = False
        StudentName = InputBox("Enter a Name Please!", "Search")
        For i As Integer = 0 To (objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Count - 1)
            If CStr(objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows(i)("Student_Name")) = StudentName Then
                StudentFound = True
                cboStudents.SelectedIndex = i
            FillStudentDetails()
            FillModuleDetails()
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = cboStudents.SelectedItem - 1
    If (rowIndex < objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Count - 1) Then
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        cboStudents.SelectedIndex = rowIndex
        FillStudentDetails()
        FillModuleDetails()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No more records to display", "End")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    Dim objRow As DataRow

    objRow = objDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows.Find(txtStudentID.Text)
    'Remember that all related child rows will be deleted! So no need to 
    'set up a new datarow for the Pet table
    objRow.Delete()
    objStudentDA.Update(objDataSet, "Students")

    Retrieve()

End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = cboStudents.SelectedItem - 1
    If (rowIndex > 0) Then
        rowIndex = rowIndex - 1
        cboStudents.SelectedIndex = rowIndex
        FillStudentDetails()
        FillModuleDetails()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No more records to display", "Start")
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: What is confusing about the message?  If a record has child records which refer to it, you cant delete the 'parent' first.  Also Visual Studio has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Please try to post only the relevant code to your problem. A [mcve] is the best option

Answer (score 0):

You try to remove a record which has child records. Due to those references your removal fails. The reason is that the Student has Modules. You will need to remove the references to the Student before you can remove it.